# How to stay zoomed in emacs rnw

Tags: emacs, knitr, sweave

I am writing using knitr/sweave and hence working from an rnw file in emacs. When I zoom (c-+) the enhanced buffer only stays zoomed in for a little while before reverting back to standard font size. I have none of these problems using regular tex files or other file types in emacs

Any ideas?

Comment: C-+ is not a well-defined standard keystroke. Which graphical environment and Emacs version are you using? Is this keystroke a feature of the graphical environment or of some Emacs plug-in?

Comment: Maybe you mean `C-x +` (or`C-x =`) instead of `C-+`?

Comment: Consider providing a step-by-step to reproduce the behavior, saying at each step what you see and what you want/expect to see instead. Start from `emacs -Q` (no init file). And it's not clear from the question what knitr/sweave/mw are or what relevance they have to the problem. If they are not relevant to the recipe to repro the problem, please remove them.